# Vim BufLeave event weird behaviour with <c-w><c-f>

Tags: autocmd

#### How to reproduce

1. Run `vim --clean` on a file that contains another filename.
2. Now run these commands

```
:set number relativenumber
:autocmd BufLeave * set norelativenumber | echoerr "BufLeave triggered"
```

3. Now use `<C-w><C-f>` on the filename to open it up in a new window.

#### Expected behaviour

I expect this command to do `set norelativenumber` on the original buffer when opening the other file on another window. Just like it is when you just move around in your windows containing different buffers with `<C-w><C-w>`.

#### What happens

The event is triggered, but `set norelativenumber` isn't ran on the left buffer.

It looks to me as a bug, am I missing something ?

I'm running Vim version 8.2.1821 by the way.

Comment: Can you edit your post to better describe what you expect the behavior to be? What are you trying to do? Set `norelativenumber` in the buffer you are leaving?

Comment: Here you go man !

Comment: `'relativenumber'` is a window-local option, not a buffer-local one.  Use `WinLeave` instead of `BufLeave`.  Also, `<c-v><c-f>` does not open the filepath under the cursor; `<c-w><c-f>` does.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it ! Can you post an answer so I choose you as Best Answer ?

Comment: I will write an answer and post it in a few minutes/hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'relativenumber'` is a window-local option, not a buffer-local one, so it makes more sense to use `WinLeave` instead of `BufLeave`.  During my limited tests, it seemed to fix your issue.  That is `'relativenumber'` was reset when leaving a window after pressing `<c-w><c-f>` on a filepath:

```
vim9script
set number relativenumber
autocmd WinLeave * set norelativenumber
mkdir('/tmp/test_nornu', 'p')
writefile(['hello, I am file1'], '/tmp/test_nornu/file1')
var lines =<< trim END
    some text line
    /tmp/test_nornu/file1
    another text line
END
writefile(lines, '/tmp/test_nornu/file2')
e /tmp/test_nornu/file2
norm! 2G
winnr()->getwinvar('&rnu', -1)->assert_equal(1)
exe "wincmd \<c-f>"
winnr('#')->getwinvar('&rnu', -1)->assert_equal(0)
echom v:errors
```

For more info, see [:help 'rnu'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27rnu%27):

```
'relativenumber' 'rnu'  boolean (default off)
                        local to window
```